# DataTable Select Query with daterange

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable in which there are 4 Columns UserName,Value,StartDate,EndDate Which has values like below format.When i select between these date range it's count is 0 but the datatable has values. Pls help me .

```
UserName | Value |StartDate             |EndDate 
joe      | 4     |28-08-2015 12:12:26 AM|30-08-2015 12:29:26 PM|


DataRow[] drDocDetails = dtDLCD.Select("UserName =\'" + sUserName + "\' AND Value =\'" + 
                         Value + "\' AND StartDate >= #" + 
                         Convert.ToDateTime(sProcessStart).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt") + 
                         "# AND EndDate < #" + 
                         Convert.ToDateTime(sProcessEnd).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt") + "#");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working for me, just check my code

```
        string sUserName ="joe";
        string Value ="4";
        string sProcessStart = "28-08-2015 12:12:26 AM";
        string sProcessEnd = "30-08-2015 12:29:26 PM";

        DataTable dtDLCD = new DataTable();

        DataColumn dtcolumn = new DataColumn("UserName");
        dtcolumn.DefaultValue = "joe";
        dtDLCD.Columns.Add(dtcolumn);

        DataColumn dtcolumn1 = new DataColumn("Value");
        dtcolumn1.DefaultValue = "4";
        dtDLCD.Columns.Add(dtcolumn1);

        DataColumn dtcolumn3 = new DataColumn("StartDate",typeof(DateTime));
        dtcolumn3.DefaultValue = "28-08-2015 12:12:26 AM";
        dtDLCD.Columns.Add(dtcolumn3);

        DataColumn dtcolumn4 = new DataColumn("EndDate", typeof(DateTime));
        dtcolumn4.DefaultValue = "30-08-2015 12:29:26 PM";
        dtDLCD.Columns.Add(dtcolumn4);

        DataRow drow = dtDLCD.NewRow();
        dtDLCD.Rows.Add(drow);


        DataRow[] drDocDetails = dtDLCD.Select("UserName = '" + sUserName + 
                                               "' AND Value = '" + Value + 
                                               "' AND StartDate = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(sProcessStart).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt") +
                                               "' AND EndDate = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(sProcessEnd).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt") + "'");

        int count = drDocDetails.Count();
```

Comment: Why down vote ? check it in console and put down vote :-/
Copy and past code to console application don't simply give down vote